# .Net Framework Installation

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I had developed an application using .NET 2.0 and database as Sql Server 2005. When I installed my application in another PC, it asks for ".NET framework required".

Is it important to have .NET Framework or else without .NET Framework shall we install ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET framework is a necessary pre-requisite on client machines wishing to run any software written for any version of the .NET framework before 4.0. With 4.0, you can also potentially opt to deploy the client profile instead of the whole framework.

The downloads are here:

- [2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&displaylang=en)
- [3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325fd-ae52-4e35-b531-508d977d32a6&displaylang=en)
- [4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en)
- [4.0 Client Profile](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=992cffcb-f8ce-41d9-8bd6-31f3e216285c&displaylang=en) (4.0).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need the have the .net framework installed - your program depends on it. Same for the Sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes--if you developed with .NET 2.0 (presumably Visual Studio 2005 or higher), then the code you made cannot run without a local installation of the .NET Framework.

Fortunately, if you're creating the application setup with Visual Studio, you can easily [add the required .NETfx installation to your setup file by clicking the right prerequisite checkbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz%28VS.80%29.aspx).